# Cannot set default value in <field> component - redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

```
<Field
  key={`specialField${FieldID}`}
  props={{required:RequiredField}}
  name={`specialField${FieldID}`}
  label={`${LangFieldName}:`}
  errorMessage={signUpLanguage[`lblValidDropdownSpecialFieldSentence`]}  
  defaultValue={'213'}
  component={RenderSelect}>
    {<option value=''>{lblSelectOneStatus}</option>}
    {FieldOptions.map(({OptionID, OptionLabel}) => 
     <option key={OptionID} value={OptionID}>{OptionLabel}</option>
    )}
```

Hi, i am trying to set the default value by the defaultValue prop in field component (redux form field). But it is not setting to default. can some one help.

Comment: Do you render an option that has the default `213` value?

Comment: yes i do. options having value 210 to 215 .

Comment: I would check the type, should you instead pass a number? E.g. `defaultValue={213}`